# Question about installation: Does Re-installing ubuntu over previous Ubuntu partition delete files?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, bootloader

I installed windows 8,1 and I think the bootloader got messed up and I tried the "check disk for errors" when you first boot the installer and it fixed them, but ubuntu wouldn't start. I have the try to launch from my bios since the GRUB doens't appear.  So I'm thinking about installing it again, but I wanna keep the files. Would re-installing it again delete files? I'm afriad choosing the option "Reinstall over ubuntu" will delete my windows 8.1 partition.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk2GF.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdyRh.png

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with Microsoft. They decided that there would only be 1 OS on the drive, so when you loaded Windows, the bootloader from Windows has only that partition as bootable. There is a easy fix using [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).